# How to split my .graphqls file into multiple files?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I searched a lot for a response to my question but none answered what I really want. I'm learning graphql and I made a little project with Spring boot using this dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Every thing works fine until now but my .graphqls file grows fast and I think it will not be readable as my app progress:

```
type User {
id: ID!,
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
email: String,
posts: [Post]
}

type Post {
id: ID!,
description: String,
user: User
}

type Query {
users:[User]
user(id: ID):User
posts:[Post]
}

type Mutation {
createUser(user: UserInput):User
}

input UserInput {
firstName: String!,
lastName: String!,
 email: String!
}
```

My question is how can I split this file into multiple files(example: 1 file to declare User type, user queries and mutations and another file to declare Posts, with query and mutation).
I tried to split this file but always only one type works and the other throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one type of a particular name per schema. But when using SDL, you can use [type extension](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Object-Extensions) syntax to add on to an existing type:

```
type Query {
  users: [User!]!
  user(id: ID): User
}

extend type Query {
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, extend worked for Query type. But can I declare `User` type and `Post` type in different files? Is there a keyword like `export` in javascript to access a type from another file. I'm sorry for the dumb question I'm new in graphql.

Comment: Your type definitions will be concatenated into a single document, so there is no need to "import" a type. You can define it in one file and then just reference it inside another.